# Webpack Lazy Loading with Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a problem with lazy loading and webpack.

There is a video of Sean Larkin showing how easy it is with webpack 4 to create a lazy loaded bundle ([Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQBAQh5AFwA)). But when I try to do it with typescript I run into some problems.

```
index.ts

export const someThing = something => import("./lazy/lazy");
```

and

```
lazy/lazy.ts
export default "I am lazy";
```

when I run it without any webpack configuration and name the files to ".js" I get a main chunk and a small chunk for the lazy loaded module.

But when I run it as ".ts" files with a simple webpack configuration I get just the "main.js" file and no extra chunk.

```
webpack.config.js
let config = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: ["ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
        ]
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

and

```
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
        "removeComments": true
    }
}
```

Is there something to configure I am mission? 
What exactly is the difference between the import of a "js" file to a "ts" file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dynamic imports are an ES feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), you need to tell TypeScript to transform to ESNext to get `import` on the output, just change `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "esnext"`.

Take this code :

```
export const LoadMe = () => import('./a-module')
```

- `"module": "commonjs"` compiles to `module.exports.LoadMe = () => require('a-module')`, Webpack can't know if it's dynamic or just a normal `require`
- `"module": "esnext"` compiles to `export const LoadMe = () => import('a-module')`, Webpack knows it's dynamic because it's a call expression to `import`

Comment: thank you. That helps ;) Now I just have to make my code work with esnext ;)

Comment: How are you able to import plugins into your webpack.config.ts file, if you're using `"module": "esnext"`? I get a bunch of syntax errors whenever I try to import/require modules into my webpack file.

Comment: I don't use TypeScript for my Webpack config, but if you do you can use `const module = require('somewhere')` instead of `import module from 'somewhere'`. You might need `@types/node` to get `require` to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to configure the Typescript compiler to not touch certain imports.
The [old way](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requireensure) of lazy loading works just as well though:

```js
require.ensure([], require => {
  const lodash = require('lodash') as typeof import('lodash');
}, 'lodash-chunk');
```

this can be wrapped in a promise to achieve a very similar behavior to the ES6 `import`

```js
function importLodash(): Promise<typeof import('lodash')> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        require.ensure([], require => {
            resolve(require('lodash'))
        }, reject, 'lodash-chunk');
    })
}

// then use it

const lodash = await importLodash();
```

*note- `require.ensure` is not generic - this function will need to be duplicated for every module you want to lazy load.

You'll also need to declare the `require.ensure` interface based on your enabled libs. I use this in my custom typings file

```js
/* typings.d.ts */

declare global {
    const require: {
        // declare webpack's lazy loading interface
        ensure(deps: string[], cb: (lazyRequire: (path: string) => any) => void, chunkName: string): void;
        ensure(deps: string[], cb: (lazyRequire: (path: string) => any) => void, errCb: (err: Error) => void, chunkName: string): void;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick one to lazyLoad a module with its type:

`function lazyLoad(){ 
    return let lazyModule:typeof import('xxx') = require('xxx');
}`

limitation: **the xxx can only be string not a variable**.