# typescript dynamic import clashes with webpack.config in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, webpack, dynamic, tsconfig

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom","esnext"],
    // "module": "commonjs",
    "module": "esNext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

```
//webpack.config.ts
import merge from 'webpack-merge'
import base from './webpack.base'
import webpack from 'webpack';
// ...
```

With configuration above, when I run `npm run build`, it throws error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import merge from 'webpack-merge';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
```

I found the solution that I should use `"module": "commonjs"`, that's no doubt that webpack runs in node environment.

While dynamic import of webpack needs `"module": "esNext"` in `tsconfig.json`, 
and if I use `"module": "commonjs"` configuration, webpack with `webpackChunkName` doesn't work.

My dynamic-import code is like this, along with configuration in babel.

```
const starsDance = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "starsDance" */'./game-stars-dance')
```

I can't find the finally solution through many googles, how could I do? And thanks very much for help.

Comment: [a relative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410022/webpack-lazy-loading-with-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing `ts-node` before trying to run the `webpack --mode production` command causing issues. I believe ts-node is used to transform the `webpack.config.ts` file into something node can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely missing `ts-node`. Install it and try again

```sh
npm install ts-node -D
```

Related answer with more information about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137188/288906