# My module is not chunked by webpack typescript with React.lazy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lazy-loading, react-router-dom, webpack-4

I am using dynamic routes (react-router-dom) as mention below

**Routes**

```
const Home = React.lazy(() => import("../../home"));

const Page2Component = React.lazy(() => import("../../page2Component"));

const ROUTES: RoutesInterface[] = [
    
    {
        id: "home",
        to: HOME_URL,
        exact: true,
        type: RouteType.ROUTE,
        Component: Home,
    },
    {
        id: "page_2",
        to: PAGE_2_URL,
        exact: true,
        type: RouteType.ROUTE,
        // @ts-ignore
        Component: Page2Component
    }]
```

**Router Mapping Component**

```
import ROUTES from "./ducks/routes";

export default class Routes extends React.Component<RoutesPropsInterface> {
    constructor(props: RoutesPropsInterface) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const { meta, analytics } = this.props;
        const componentProps = {
            analytics,
            appmeta: meta,
        };
        return (
            <Router>
                <Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
                    <NavigationWithRouter />
                    <Switch>
                        {ROUTES.map(({ id, to, from, type, exact, Component }: RoutesInterface) =>
                            type === RouteType.ROUTE ?
                            <Route
                                key={id}
                                path={to}
                                exact={exact}
                                render={(routeProps: RouteComponentProps) => <Component
                                    {...componentProps}
                                    {...routeProps}
                                />}
                            /> :
                            <Redirect
                                key={id}
                                from={from}
                                to={to}
                                exact={exact}
                            />
                        )}
                    </Switch>
                </Suspense>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

when I debugged the route before mapping I can see it's about to map the lazy-loaded component.

[image]

Whereas when I checked the final bundled code, its only 2 chunks my `vendors` and `srcmain`

Why the lazy bundeling is not working here in my case ?  Since the webpack4 supports the lazy is there any other config.

**Solution**

1. Instead for using `module:"commonsjs` it was required to use `module:"esnext"` for my tsconfig , very well [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410101/3345331)
2. Some other (old route file) was also getting imported, though I am not invoking that import in my file webpack was bundling that and ignoring my lazy routing.

Comment: Absolute lifesaver, you should post the "Solution" as an answer.